# UML use-case diagram - IF condition?

Tags: uml, use-case

I need to create UML use case diagram for my application. Application allows to create documents and share it between users. Document needs to be approved by people who will be selected by DOCUMENT_CREATOR. (DOCUMENT_CREATOR can create his own groups with people) and after approval of all this people, document will be shared among the readers. After final approval, email will be sent to all approvers that document has been successfuly approved or when someone of approvers will not be OK with document, then email should be sent, that document is now blocked... Then scheduler should send email to readers, that they can read new document... scheduler also block passed documents (when time for voting runs out).

1. Is my UML use case diagram correct?
2. When user approves the document, It does not automatically send the email - it will send email only, when all other approvers has already voted. So there should be something like (IF ALL OTHER APPROVERS HAS VOTED) -> then send email, else DO NOTHING.

Thanks for help

[image: My UML diagram]

Comment: I'm not sure if your "send email to ..." use cases really should be use cases. Feels like they might just be an alternate scenario. They don't have enough merit on their own, and they don't seem to be reused either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your diagram looks just fine. Regarding no. 2: You can simply attach a constraint to the `<<include>>` telling the condition you noted above. 
[image]

Usually this is part of the scenario steps inside a UC. However, exposing these constraints on top level might be useful in certain cases. So no objection on doing that here.